# Jpanel Printing on PersonaC30 card printer

Tags: java, swing, printing

I am using PersonaC30 card printer to print my Jpanel data on card. My print method is working fine with paper printer, but when i print with card printer it's not printing my data. It's printing well externally but its not working with my application.

Here is my code:

```
private void printCard(){

PrinterJob printjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
printjob.setJobName(" TESSCO CUSTOMER CARD ");

printjob.setPrintable (new Printable() {

public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum){

    Paper card = pf.getPaper();
   // card.setImageableArea(0, 0, 153, 243);
    card.setSize(243, 154);
    pf.setPaper(card);
    pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);

if (pageNum > 0){
return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
}
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;

g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
g2.translate( 0f, 0f );

jLayeredPane2.paint(g2);

return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
}
});
if (printjob.printDialog() == false)
return;

try {
        printjob.print();
      }
      catch (PrinterException ex) {
        System.out.println("NO PAGE FOUND."+ex);

      }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. I added some code to resize the image of the panel.

```
private void printCard() {

    PrinterJob printjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    printjob.setJobName(" TESSCO CUSTOMER CARD ");

    Printable printable = new Printable() {

        public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum) {

            if (pageNum > 0) {
                return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }

            Dimension size = jLayeredPane2.getSize();
            BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

            jLayeredPane2.print(bufferedImage.getGraphics());

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;
            g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
            g2.drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, (int) pf.getWidth(), (int) pf.getHeight(), null);

            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
    };

    Paper paper = new Paper();
    paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, 153, 243);
    paper.setSize(243, 154);

    PageFormat format = new PageFormat();
    format.setPaper(paper);
    format.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);

    printjob.setPrintable(printable, format);
    if (printjob.printDialog() == false)
        return;

    try {
        printjob.print();
    } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        System.out.println("NO PAGE FOUND." + ex);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much its absolutely work fine. Thank for your help Emre.