# Printing a BufferedImage in Java

Tags: java, image, printing, bufferedimage

Does anyone know how to print a BufferedImage in Java?

Comment: Print it where, Canvas or somwhere else ?

Comment: first i have tried to print all components from a jpanel, but when i printed it, there was only one button on the page. Then I found out how to make a picture of the components, so i thought that it is easier to print an image. but i haven't found anything about printing an bufferedimage on the internet

Comment: @Chuck - Or printing on paper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing is just like drawing on the screen, so eventually you get a Graphics object, and you just drawImage into it.

Comment: @FelixKnorr Can u please code spinet to print the buffered image as i also have same need?Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by print. Print on a printer? Print to standard out? Write to a file?

You can check out this tutorial from sun. If you're looking to write to a file. Open in your favorite image tool and print from there.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/saveimage.html

If you're building a graphical app and using something like AWT you can using the java printing API which would probably require some tap dancing.

Comment: @Felix Check out this StackOverflow Post. This john is printing a BufferedImaged with swing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776621/jpanel-printing-please-someone-help

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do that by extending BufferedImage to implement the Printable interface like so (a collage of code I found from around the web):

```
package components;
import java.awt.image.PixelGrabber;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.Image.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.net.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.Integer;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.lang.String;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.imageio.stream.*;
import java.lang.ClassLoader.*;
import java.lang.Class;
import java.io.*;
import javax.print.*;
import javax.print.attribute.*;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.*;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaSize.*;
import javax.print.event.*;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import javax.print.attribute.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import java.awt.image.ColorModel;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.awt.image.IndexColorModel;
import java.awt.print.Printable.*;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class printableBufferedImage extends BufferedImage implements Printable
{
   public printableBufferedImage(ColorModel cm, WritableRaster raster, boolean     isRasterPremultiplied, Hashtable properties) 
   {
      super(cm, raster, isRasterPremultiplied, properties);
   }
   public printableBufferedImage(int width, int height, int imageType)
   {
      super(width, height, imageType);
   }
   public printableBufferedImage(int width, int height, int imageType, IndexColorModel cm) 
   {
      super(width, height, imageType, cm);
   }


public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws
                                                    PrinterException {

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    if (page > 0) { /* We have only one page, and 'page' is zero-based */
        return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    }

    /* User (0,0) is typically outside the imageable area, so we must
     * translate by the X and Y values in the PageFormat to avoid clipping
     */

     try
    {

     g2d.setClip(0,0,2100,3300);
     g2d.drawImage(this, 225, 0,null);
     g2d.drawImage(this,225, 1550,null);
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
    }
    /* tell the caller that this page is part of the printed document */
      //return NO_SUCH_PAGE;
    return PAGE_EXISTS;
}

 public BufferedImage resizeOurImageFromImage(BufferedImage OurImage, int targetWidth, int targetHeight)
 throws Exception
 {
   double tempWidth, tempHeight;
   int w,h,type;
   Boolean OurImageHasAlpha;
   OurImageHasAlpha = OurImage.getColorModel().hasAlpha();
   if(OurImageHasAlpha)
   {
      type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
   }
   else
   {
      type = BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB;
   }


   w = OurImage.getWidth();
   h = OurImage.getHeight();

   if((targetWidth == 0) && (targetHeight != 0))
   {
      targetWidth = (targetHeight * w) / h;
   }
   else
   {
     if((targetHeight == 0) && (targetWidth != 0))
     {
       targetHeight = (targetWidth * h) / w;
     }
   }

   if((targetHeight == 0) || (targetWidth == 0))
   {
     throw(new Exception("In the Resize Image module with one dimension still zero after trying proportion"));
   }
        do
        {
           if(w > targetWidth)
           {
              tempWidth = ((double) w)/1.2;
              if (tempWidth < (double) targetWidth)
              {
                 w = targetWidth;
              }
              else
              {
                 w = (int) java.lang.Math.round(tempWidth + 0.49);
              }
           }
           else
           {
             w = targetWidth;
           }
           if(h > targetHeight)
           {
             tempHeight = ((double) h)/1.2;
             if (tempHeight < (double) targetHeight)
             {
                h = targetHeight;
             }
             else
             {
                 h = (int) java.lang.Math.round(tempHeight + 0.49);
             }
          }
          else
          {
            h = targetHeight;
          }
          BufferedImage tmp = new BufferedImage(w, h, type);
          Graphics2D g2 = tmp.createGraphics();
          g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
          g2.drawImage(OurImage, 0, 0, w, h, null);
          g2.dispose();
          OurImage = tmp;
          } while ((targetHeight != h) || (targetWidth != w));

   return OurImage;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check my solved problem here:
[Java PrinterJob, high quality printing ends up with 72 DPI anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59622698/java-printerjob-high-quality-printing-ends-up-with-72-dpi-anyway/59633319#59633319)
the solution was to draw the image to paintComponent(Graphics g) method for a JPanel and pass this panel to Print utility class, at that class you can easily scale the image/Panel as you want preserving the image high quality, it sounds the same but the result was not, i read an advice about using the image outside "onscreen graphics context" but had no idea how to do that until i tried this solution, try it