# Printing a Bufferedimage object in specific size

Tags: java, swing, printing, bufferedimage, java-2d

I have created a buffered image with specific pixel size and i tried to send it to printer dialog but when i send it to printer the size is way to big for my goal (card printer)

this is my object :

```
BufferedImage bi
```

and this is what i've tried so far including my object :

[Printing a BufferedImage in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283860/printing-a-bufferedimage-in-java)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/printing/dialog.html

and a few more examples and i couldnt find an answer

what im looking for is a simple way to send my bufferedimage to printing dialog with the height/width that currect for my card printer .
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> I have created a buffered image with specific pixel size and i tried
>   to send it to printer dialog but when i send it to printer the size is
>   way to big for my goal (card printer)

- have look at [public Image getScaledInstance(int width, int height, int hints)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getScaledInstance%28int,%20int,%20int%29), there you can to set required ratio in pixels
- notice `ScaledInstance` is asynchronous,
- have to call `flush()` in some cases, when `XxxImage`, `Icon`, `ImageIcon` is placed in `JLabel`

Comment: the image size is known already , my problem is to send it to the print dialog with the exact size

Comment: @Adir.el not sure for all printers but DPI equals pixels ratio, carrefully for some color printers there are DPI = DPI * number of printing cartriges, multiple of each printers head :-)